# Creating a crystal report in a web service that uses XMLRPC

Tags: web-services, crystal-reports

I have looked into everything but I think this is a unique problem. I have a web service in my website. This web service uses XMLRPC.NET but that hardly matters. i use this web service to get the string sent by the client and convert it into XML.This all is working fine. But the real problem is: I have a .aspx that uses the above written xml to generate a crystal report and save it as a PDF. The problem is I cannot call the .aspx page from my web service as response. redirect does not work. I tried writing the complete crystal report generation and PDF save  logic in the web service method but it does not work because the CrystalReportViewer1.reportsource gives an error as it does not recognize the CrystalReportViewer1 in the current context. is there any way that I can do this by redirecting or by using the crystal report logic in the web service or any other way. Seems a little complicated but any help will be greatly appreciated. Please need help.

Thank You